# Pass mutiple PHP variables in URL

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to pass 2 PHP variables to a controller function.

```
anchor('Controller/Function/'.$var1, 'Help', 'title="Help"');
```

That is how I am passing one variable. How can I pass two variables? Preferably without using an array.

Comment: title=¨Help¨&content="Hi".  Look up GET parameters

Comment: [Get](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php), and [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) allow you to pass more than 1 var between pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
anchor('Controller/Function/'.$var1.'/'.$var2, 'Help', 'title="Help"');
```

After use URI CLASS

=> https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I thought it should be, but it doesn't want to work for me for some reason.